# Update table based on 2nd table without using the key

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenario like the following:

TABLE_1

```
ID  DESC    TABLE2REF

1   1stRow  2
2   2ndRow  4
3   3rdRow  5
4   4thRow  3
5   5thRow  4
6   6thRow  5
```

TABLE_2

```
ID  DESC 
1   Apples
2   Pears
3   Figs
4   Oranges
5   Grapes
```

Without using actual values of TABLE2REF (which assume is a foreign key to TABLE 2 ID), I want to create an update query that updates TABLE 1 rows currently referencing Oranges or Grapes, to instead reference Figs).

I tried:

I have tried various queries without success. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your actual problem is.  You need `table2ref` -- either implicitly or explicitly -- if you want to understand the referring values.

The following identifies the rows that are `Oranges` or `Grapes` without using `table2`:

```
update table1
    set table2ref = 3
    where table2ref in (4, 5);
```

You can alternatively do this as:

```
update table1
    set table2ref = 3
    where in (5, 6);
```

But, the right way to do this is:

```
update table1
    set table2ref = (select id from table2 where description = 'Figs')
    where table2ref in (select id from table2 where description in ('Oranges', 'Grapes'));
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon. Yes, "the right way" is what I needed and it worked. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a genrale way this can help you:

```
UPDATE table1 tab1 SET table2ref = tab2.id 
FROM table2 tab2 
WHERE tab2.id = tab1.table2ref
```